# How to create custom dynamic url

Tags: plugin-development, routing

I want to create my own url like this 
http://localhost/wptest/content/programs/trainings-conferences/

I have create my own plugin and use this code.

```
add_action('init','wpyog_add_rewrite_rules');
add_action('init','wpyog_add_rewrite_rules');

function wpyog_add_rewrite_rules(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^content/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?content_category=$matches[1]content_slug=$matches[2]','top');
}

add_action('query_vars','wpyog_add_query_vars');
function wpyog_add_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'content_category';
    $qvars[] = 'content_slug';
    return $qvars;
}

add_action('template_redirect','wpyog_template_redirect');
function wpyog_template_redirect(){
   if( get_query_var('content_slug') && get_query_var('content_category') ) 
  {
    include( WPYog_Ukraine_PATH.'templates/frontend_template.php' );
    exit();
    }
 }
```

But its not working its shows 404 page. While I am using this url its works http://localhost/wptest/?category=programs&category_slug=trainings-conferences

Comment: Missing & in rewrite pattern.

Comment: @birgire Can you please correct it in proper way

Comment: also did you resave/flush the permalinks after changing the rewrite rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your rewrite patern miss a "&" between `$matches[1]` & `content_slug`

```
function wpyog_add_rewrite_rules(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^content/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?content_category=$matches[1]&content_slug=$matches[2]','top');
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me to generate without content word. Such as http://localhost/wptest/programs/trainings-conferences/  . Is it will effect page and subpages url

Comment: just take off content/ from the rule

Comment: I have create add_rewrite_rule('^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?news_detail=$matches[1]news_category=$matches[2]news_slug=$matches[3]','top');  Want something like  http://localhost/wptest/news/economic-development/testing-news-content/

Comment: and, does-it works ?

Comment: No this not work. But also not showing 404 error

Comment: have you flush permalinks after adding it ?

Comment: Yes I have done

Comment: use plugin rewrite rules inspector to see what it provides